# Ubuntu Core - Creating user failed

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-core

I have a https://login.ubuntu.com/ account (with the SSH Keys). But when I try to install ubuntu core I always get the error: 
error: while creating user: cannot create user "my email".:...

No idea where to go from here. Does it take long for Ubuntu to update their DB?.

Comment: Exactly what commands are you trying, and what output do you get ?

Comment: First step installing after setting network.
That error message its the only thing I get